# NodeJS a correr na Porta 80 com Apache

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Bom, é o seguinte, sempre que pretendo utilizar socket.io tenho que utilizar alguma porta, com que faz que sempre que eu queira ter acesso a pagina web que trabalha com o socket.io tenho que ir a : wwww.meusite.com:porta.

O que gostava de saber é se posso remover a porta, ou se pelo menos existe alguma solução de evitar este problema, tendo em conta que o apache do meu servidor, já utiliza a porta 80.

Comment: Não é "sem porta", há sempre porta, mas o browser por default esconde a 80 e, se não estou em erro a 8080 também. Podes testar isso se fores a www.exemplo.com:80 . Mas creio que o que queres é isto: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-can-i-get-node-js-to-listen-on-port-80 ou http://stackoverflow.com/a/6109171/3162303. Podes editar a pergunta para ser mais claro nesse aspeto

Comment: É só usar a porta 80

Comment: O problema é que se usar a porta 80, entra em conflito com o apache que tenho no servidor.

Comment: Se Node não é o único servidor no ambiente deves fazer um proxy (com ou sem SSL)

Comment: Como assim, proxy? Pode dar mais detalhes...

Comment: @Gonçalo deves ter de configurar o servidor apache para servir essa app nessa porta. Pus uns links acima que podem ajudar.

Comment: Se eu tiver um ip dedicado diferente, que aponta para o mesmo servidor, consigo ter o apache e o nodejs a rodar com a mesma porta, mas cada um com o ip respetivo?

Comment: @Gonçalo Agora com a sua edição minha resposta ficou parcialmente sem sentido, por favor não faça esse tipo de edição que muda o sentido inicial da pergunta.

Comment: Peço desculpa jbueno, eu mudei para tentar especificar melhor o meu problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toda requisição é feita em uma porta, o que acontece é que o browser "esconde" as portas 80 e 443 que são as duas padrões do protocolo HTTP - sem SSL e com SSL, respectivamente.

Por definição, se você não especificar nenhuma porta numa requisição HTTP, esta requisição será feita na porta 80.

Comment: O problema é que se utilizar a porta 80, entra em conflito com a porta do apache do servidor.

Comment: Ou você desativa o apache ou faz com que ele não responda mais na porta 80, fora isso não tem muito o que fazer.

Comment: Deves fazer um proxy no Apache

Comment: É, ou redireciona do Apache pro node.

Comment: Se eu tiver um ip dedicado diferente, que aponta para o mesmo servidor, consigo ter o apache e o nodejs a rodar com a mesma porta, mas cada um com o ip respetivo?

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, eu tinha colocado mal o script no index.html, o que fez com que estivesse a ler de forma incorreta pelo socket.io, afinal posso utilizar qualquer porta, que não ocorre o problema.